# Overriding or preventing an external .js file from loading in Chrome/tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I have a page with the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="domainstuff/evil.js"></script>
```

It has the following thing:

```
var input = ":input[type=text]";
jQuery(function(input) 
{
    jQuery(input).bind('focusout', function(e) 
    {
        //...etc
    }
}
```

It overrides my js:

```
document.addEventListener("focusout", function (e)
    {
         //etc
    }
```

I've tried in tampermonkey

```
jQuery(input).unbind("focusout");
```

and also

```
jQuery(input).off("focusout");
```

but I don't think I am able to target the evil.js's function.

I can't find the SO question again, but I read someone suggested to use

```
// @run-at document-start
```

and

```
// @run-at document-end
```

but both don't prevent the evil.js file from loading.

To be honest, I've been able to block the script with uBlock Origin, and my script finally works, but I just want to know if it's possible to override a function (event?) in an external .js file.

Comment: Can't you simply remove the 'evil.js' ?

Comment: So are you trying to stop a function that **evil.js** is going to try to fire or are you trying to prevent any code within **evil.js** from loading and running?

Comment: @Roberrrt it is not my website. The people maintaining it will not allow me to touch their source code and it's causing a lot of grief for the clerks doing about 400 data entries a day, and they will not listen to our complaints because they have to make a website that pleases many other people.

Comment: @zero298 I would like to do either, as long as mine will run over theirs. But evil.js only has one function to be honest and it's that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input in this case, is a variable, given that you're loading the JavaScript after the initial evil script:

`jQuery(input).off("focusout");`

will not work, but:

`jQuery(':input[type=text').off("focusout");`

Should work.

Now you'll have to make sure that this applies after the document is loaded and the JavaScript gets executed, so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(':input[type=text').off("focusout");
}
```

In case this doesn't work either, the `off()` is still being called before the initial eventListener gets applied, so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery(':input[type=text').off("focusout");
    }, 500);
}
```

Will wait half a second after loading before removing the focusout, after which you can apply the new event listener.

Comment: (And yes, this is a very non-elegant solution, but since OP cannot control the original source code, this should solve his problem).